# Two dimensional array with 3x3 display

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been working on this all week. Yes, it is homework, and I realize this same thing has been somewhat asked before but I cant make the solutions work for **my specific code**. I need to make a two dimensional array have a display that is `3x3`. I have to use the **array**, it is part of the assignment, and it must be `3x3` and have a `print` method, so these are not changes I can make.

Right now they are **printing out in one single line**. Here is the result I am getting:

[image]

If you cant see the screenshot, the result I was getting was:

> First Tic Tac Toe:
>   `X   O   X   O   O   X   X   X   O`
>   Second Tic Tac Toe:
>   `O   O   X   O   O   X   X   X   O`

Here is my code:

```
public class tictactoe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First Tic Tac Toe: ");
        char[][] ttt1 = { { 'X', 'O', 'X' }, { '0', 'O', 'X' }, { 'X', 'X', 'O' } };
        print(ttt1);

        System.out.println("Second Tic Tac Toe: ");
        char[][] ttt2 = { { 'O', 'O', 'X' }, { '0', 'O', 'X' }, { 'X', 'X', 'O' } };
        print(ttt2);
    }

    public static void print(char ttt1[][]) {
        for (char row = 0; row < ttt1.length; row++) {
            for (char column = 0; column < ttt1[row].length; column++)
                System.out.print(ttt1[row][column] + "     ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fine. You did a good job at asking a well formatted and structured question. It contains a small code example that demonstrates the problem, the current output, the desired output and an explanation (compare to [ask] and [mcve]). Well done, have my upvote.

Comment: By the way, please stick to Java **naming conventions**. Class names should be CamelCase, so `TicTacToe`. At least ensure that the first character is uppercase. Also, if we call `static` methods we usually add the classname as identifier in front, so that everyone directly sees that we are calling a `static` method. So it should be `TicTacToe.print(ttt2);` in your `main` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a new line once you print out each row.

```
public static void print(char ttt1[][]) {
    for (char row = 0; row < ttt1.length; row++) {
        for (char column = 0; column < ttt1[row].length; column++)
            System.out.print(ttt1[row][column] + "     ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and I can't believe it was that simple, yet it didn't cross my mind. Definitely won't make that mistake again! Thank you so very much!